# Which docker client and daemon is used by openshift origin to pull images when creating new-app?

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

When executing `oc new-app openshift/deployment-example`, which docker client and daemon origin uses to pull the image?

Answer (score 0):

It is the docker daemon and client  that is installed on that host. (Master and node)
We can setup specific properties in /etc/sysconfig/docker file if we want to modify the default registry.( ADD_REGISTRY..etc)